# Can not print integer to standard out (assembly)

Tags: assembly, int, stdout

I try to make an addition and then print the sum to standard out. But nothing is beeing printed. I read [this tutorial](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/hello.html) and just changed the text string to my 16 bit integer to be stored in the register.

```
.section .data
  x:   .int 40
  y:   .int 10
  z:   .int 30
  v:   .int 8
  sum: .int 0
  len: .int 2   # 2 bytes integer for length of sum

.section .text

.globl _start
_start:

  movl x, %eax
  addl y, %eax
  addl z, %eax
  subl v, %eax
  movl %eax, sum

 # put sum to standard out

  movl len, %edx        # third argument, length of sum
  movl sum, %ecx        # second argument: pointer to message
  movl $1, %ebx         # first argument: file handle (stdout)
  movl $4, %eax         # system call number (sys_write)

  int $0x80             # call kernel

        # exit

  movl $0, %ebx
  movl $1, %eax
  int  $0x80
```

Comment: You need to convert the integer to a string for printing. sys_write prints bytes; it doesn't interpret them.

Comment: Ok! Is there any approach when converting ints to strings?

Answer (score 2):

> Ok! Is there any approach when converting ints to strings?

For the beginning (just for testing purposes) you might use a helper program written in C.

You write one byte of message type and multiple bytes of data. The helper program will convert them. The command line will then look like this:

```
assembler_program | helper_program
```

For the real proram you'll have to convert a register value to decimal. This here is for unsigned numbers:

```
     # Print out the value of eax...
     # Prepare...
    mov %esp, %ecx
    sub $20, %esp
    mov $10, %ebx
     # Convert to decimal
next_digit:
    xor %edx,%edx
    div %ebx
    add $'0', %dl
    dec %ecx
    mov %dl, 0(%ecx)
    test %eax, %eax
    jnz next_digit
     # Calculate the size
    lea 20(%esp), %edx
    sub %ecx, %edx
     # Call int $0x80
    mov $4, %eax
    mov $1, %ebx
    int $0x80
     # Clean up
    add $20, %esp
```

For signed numbers you require following additional code:

```
    test %eax,%eax
    jns positive
    neg %eax
    push %eax
    mov $4, %eax
    mov $1, %ebx
    mov $minus, %ecx
    mov $1, %edx
    int $0x80
    pop %eax
positive:
    # Now do the unsigned output from above

minus:
    .byte '-'
```